# Why has my question been placed on hold?

Tags: discussion, android-versions

[My question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123249/how-to-whitelist-app-in-doze-mode-android-6-0) is related to Doze Mode, a feature in the Android 6.0 Preview 3 which will be released at the end of this month.

My question has been marked [On Hold] but I think it may be important for some people who need to prepare their software for the new version of Android which break some things may be important (it is for me).

Why was my question placed on hold?

Comment: You might have noticed (or not?) that our site is for ***END USERS***, who are NOT interested in "***preparing*** software" but in ***using*** it. So while it's good you care, this is the wrong place to deal with it, sorry. And no, we haven't tried anything with coding here :) XDA might be a good place to discuss such things.

Comment: Oh... so i've missed that :) sorry, my bad. And thank you for explanation, also for being friendly for newbies. See you

Answer (score 3):

As Izzy's comment has already noted, and as the post notice on your question explains:

> Questions about **writing and publishing Android apps, writing custom ROMs, and other topics that are primarily of concern to developers** are off-topic. Consider taking advantage of other resources that may be appropriate for your question.

Information about the scope of this site, including the types of questions that are permitted, can be found in our [Help Center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). For development questions, you may wish to visit [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) where you can apply the [android tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) to your question.